# Does skipping reviews stop the consecutive progress for the Rapport hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Would skipping reviews reset the progress towards the review hats (Rapport, Consensus, and Harmony)? I have done many reviews since Winter Bash started., but I haven't got the hat yet.

The description of the Rapport hat is:

> Complete eight consecutive close reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 25 on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Skipping should not be discouraged. Skipping is better than making a bad review just for retaining hat progress.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I agree, I am not a fan of this hat

Comment: That's a good question. I wondered the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question! The answer is no, skipping reviews does not affect your consecutive streak in any way to earn any of the related hats (Consensus, Rapport and Harmony). Skipped results are simply ignored when detecting "consecutive" reviews.

Comment: how about clicking *Reject and Edit* and the majority is *reject *? is that ok too?

Comment: Thanks Felippe, just also wondering about what Vickel mentioned... Would what vickel mentioned keep the streak?

Comment: In that case it would indeed break the streak, since they are technically different votes on our end!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Felippe for the confirmation. I also realized that this was actually already confirmed by @Slate [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374305/why-am-i-not-getting-the-harmony-hat#comment1247565_374357) in the comments:

> As far as I'm aware skipping reviews shouldn't reset or count towards the counter.