# Why am I not getting the Harmony hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

I reviewed more than 25 consecutive Suggested edit reviews.

I reviewed all 40 of the day at once, and all of them I either rejected or approved (or improved).

As you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708364/u12-f%CC%89%CD%8B%CC%85%CC%BE%CC%87orward?tab=activity&sort=reviews

I clicked on all of them and none of them are still under review...

Why am I not getting the Harmony hat?

## ***Edit:***

Thanks to @Slate pointing out my mistake. But now I reviewed more, the hat should deliver, but it's not delivering.

## ***Edit 2:***

More users are facing this same big with these hats.

@Panda also asked a question about this:
[Is there something more in the implementation of Rapport?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374409/is-there-something-more-in-the-implementation-of-rapport)

I am not the only one :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although @Slate's answer is absolutely correct, you should have gotten the hat after your 10 new reviews, which didn't happen.

Here's the issue:
We had a slight conversion issue when calculating if a user agreed with the "majority", this was specifically excluding 2/3 scenarios (where the user voted X, someone else voted X and a third person voted Y) and similar.

A fix for this has been pushed, and I can see that you've been awarded the hat! Congratulations!

Thanks for reporting, appreciate the help.

Comment: Yah! Got all 3 review hats now! Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, this is not a bug. You need 25 consecutive reviews where the review outcome agreed with your call. Currently, [your 16th-latest review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30629281) has an outcome (Accept) that disagreed with your call (Reject).

You currently need 10 more consecutive suggested edit reviews where the outcome agrees with your call in order to get the hat (if I've counted correctly, might be off by a couple in either direction).

Comment: But if the 16th failed, won't the count reset to zero?

Comment: @CinCout If you fail any review, the counter resets. But each subsequent successful review adds one to the counter. So U12 had some number on the counter, then their 16th latest review failed - at that point the counter reset to 0. Then, 15 successful reviews later, the counter is now at 15. If they do another 10 successful reviews, the counter will be at 25, and they will be awarded the hat.

Comment: So its not consecutive then?

Comment: It is consecutive. If any of your last 25 reviews did not agree with the consensus outcome, then you will not be awarded the hat. If all of your last 25 reviews *did* agree with the consensus outcome, you will be awarded the hat. If you miss one review, it will take 25 more successful ones after that in a row to get the hat.

Comment: Got it. Missed the *"Then, 15 successful reviews later, the counter is now at 15."* part

Comment: Makes we wonder, what happens if you Skip a review?

Comment: As far as I'm aware skipping reviews shouldn't reset or count towards the counter.

Comment: @Slate Reviewed 10 more, waiting for the approvals (or rejects) and to see if the hat triggers

Comment: @Slate those 10 are now reviewed! I should get the hat now!

Comment: @Slate: Correct. [Felippe confirms that here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374442/335251)