# Is there something more in the implementation of Rapport?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The description for [Rapport](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/rapport) states:

> Complete eight consecutive close reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count!

Here are my reviews in chronological order on a particular non-SO site:

[image: Review 1]

[image: Review 2]

[image: Review 3]

[image: Review 4]

[image: Review 5]

[image: Review 6]

[image: Review 7]

[image: Review 8]

- *^ Did this review inadvertently break the streak?*

[image: Review 9]

[image: Review 10]

Should I be getting Rapport already?

Comment: I have the same bug on SO, I got 25 consecutive and no hat. I think there is a bug with this hat.

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward Hmm, does sound like it.

Comment: Yeap, probably.

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward, you two need a SEDE script to check for you, a modification to [something like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/268970/find-low-quality-review-tasks-completed-unanimously-by-looks-ok-actions-within-th) should provide proof. This hat has been awarded, many people and myself have it, so it's not always been broken. Eight consecutive isn't too hard  to check manually, but twenty five really needs a script for error-free counting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! We had similar issues reported, here's what we found out:
We had a slight conversion issue when calculating if a user agreed with the "majority", this was specifically excluding 2/3 scenarios (where the user voted X, someone else voted X and a third person voted Y) and similar.

A fix for this has been pushed, and I can see that you've been awarded the hat! Congratulations!