# How is the consecutiveness determined for the Consensus, Rapport and Harmony hats?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

This is related to [Why am I not getting the Harmony hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374305/why-am-i-not-getting-the-harmony-hat), but it's not a duplicate of that question.

I completed 25 suggested edit review tasks where my Reject/Approve decision matched the majority of reviewers.

Here are the reviews. You can't see from the image that my vote matches the majority of voters, but you can check it [on my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history?userId=1221571&skipped=true).

[image]

In some of the reviews all the reviewers agreed with me. In others, one agreed and one disagreed (which means that, in addition to my vote, I was in the majority).

Therefore, the possible reasons I can see for not getting the Harmony hat are either:

1. a bug in the trigger
2. a misunderstanding of the "consecutive" part of the hat trigger. Does "eight consecutive suggested edit reviews" (25 on Stack Overflow) mean consecutive reviews which I voted on, or consecutive reviews that were presented to me in the review queue? If it's the latter, do I have to complete 8 (or 25) reviews in one sitting, and vote on each one of them? If it's the former, I believe I met this criteria.

Comment: Same issue with me :( [Why am I not getting the Harmony hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374305)

Comment: @double-beep thanks, but this comment doesn't apply in my case. All 25 reviews had at least one more reviewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this one out.

Turns out we had a slight conversion issue (integer division, anyone?) when calculating if a user agreed with the "majority", this was specifically excluding 2/3 scenarios (where the user voted X, someone else voted X and a third person voted Y) and similar.

A fix for this has been pushed, and I can see that you've been awarded the hat! Congratulations!

Thanks for reporting, appreciate the help.

Comment: That explains it. thanks!